# Grails assets not work in deployed .WAR

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am running an application through Intellij Idea 2016.3 and everything is working correctly, when I generate the .WAR (gradlew assemble) file the assets are not loaded in the running application and the application not working.

Grails 3.1.14
JDK 1.8.121

That is my **build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.craigburke.gradle:bower-installer-gradle:2.5.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.5"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.12"
    }
}

    version "1.0.18"
    group "veedy"

    apply plugin:"eclipse"
    apply plugin:"idea"
    apply plugin:"war"
    apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
    apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
    apply plugin:"com.craigburke.bower-installer"
    apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
    apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


    springBoot {
        executable = true
    }

    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
        gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
        }
        applyMavenExclusions false
    }

    dependencies {
        assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-template-asset-pipeline:2.2.6"
        assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:2.4.0"
        assets "com.craigburke:js-closure-wrap-asset-pipeline:1.2.0"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
        compile "org.grails:grails-core"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
        compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
        compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
        compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
        compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.0.12"
        console "org.grails:grails-console"
        profile "org.grails.profiles:angular:3.1.6"
        runtime "com.h2database:h2"
        runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
        testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
        testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
        testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
        testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
        testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"


        //custom
        compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
        compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC4"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-spring-websocket:2.3.0"
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
    }
    bower {
        'angular'('1.4.x') {
            source 'angular.js'
        }
        'angular-resource'('1.4.x') {
            source 'angular-resource.js' >> '/angular/'
        }
        'angular-mocks'('1.4.x') {
            source 'angular-mocks.js' >> '/angular/'
        }
        'angular-bootstrap'('1.1.x') {
            source 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.js' >> '/angular/'
        }
        'bootstrap'('3.x.x') {
            source 'dist/css/bootstrap.css' >> '/bootstrap/'
        }
    }

    assets {
        minifyJs = true
        minifyCss = true
    }


    bootRun {
        // local.config.location is just a random name. You can use yours.
        jvmArgs = ['-Dlocal.config.location=app-config.yml']
    }
```

and my

Comment: So try to fix it! Or at least provide more info related to details. E.g. asset-pipeline plugin version or examples of it's usage.

Comment: Thank you for the help. These are my dependences: 
<code>
classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.13.1"
apply plugin: "com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.13.1"
</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved deleting the Bower calls in gradle.build.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, with or without `war`, its working fine with below snippets in `build.gradle`.

Basically, gradle plugin for asset-pipeline needs to be mentioned. And also, in `dependencies` change it to `compile` instead of `runtime`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
       ...
    }
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.10.2"
        ...
    }
}
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
```

**UPDATE**

In my Grails application, i have the below codes:

... \grails-app\assets\javascripts\app\app.js

```
//= require_self
//= require /angular/angular.js
//= require /angular/lodash.js
//= require /angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.1.js
//= require /app/directives/directives.js

'use strict';

var app = angular
  .module('myapp', [
    'ui.bootstrap', 'directives'
  ]);
```

... \grails-app\assets\javascripts\app\directives\directives.js

```
//= require_self

angular.module("directives",[])
  .directive('bindUnsafeHtml',['$compile', function($compile) {...}]);
```

index.gsp

```
 <asset:javascript src="app/app.js" />
```

Please note: the comments like lines `//= require_self` are important for module dependency.

[Gradle Angular Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/craigburke/angular-template-asset-pipeline) has this points mentioned in the examples.

Comment: Btw, i am using grails 3.1.7

Comment: instead of runtime try using : 
compile "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made this change but still no success.

Comment: sorry to hear that the problem exists. I saw you used asset pipeline for angularjs stuff. Before proceed with `angular-template-asset-pipeline` , I would like to try with including only simple JS files.

[link](https://github.com/craigburke/angular-template-asset-pipeline)
it says that you need to use `required` things properly. Please check, in your app.js you should have something like below codes.

//= require /angular/angular
//= require /angular/angular-route
//= require_self (1)
//= require_tree /my-app/app-section/templates

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what your suggestion is. Im my app.js had this options.

Comment: @RobsonOliveira .. really sorry for late response. Let's fix a time, so that we can chat live. Surely, we can get a solution.

Comment: Give me a schedule, im in Sao Paulo, Brazil.

Comment: Please make it at 22 March @ 01 pm, Sao Paulo time.

Comment: It's a great time. If you can, add me on skype or hangout (gmail):
Skype: robsonolivesa
Hangout: robsonolivesa

Thank you

Comment: i think, we should stick to SO.

Comment: the problem still there?

Comment: The problem was solved deleting the Bower calls in gradle.build.